# Sanity Groq function - array of unique values

Tags: fetch, nuxt.js, sanity

I need some help regarding fetching some data.

I'm building blog with Nuxt3 and Sanity and I use https://sanity.nuxtjs.org/ module.

I need query to get all the unique tags from `_type article` so I can have filter by tags in my blog.

I wrote this query and It gives result back in my Sanity Vision.

```
array::unique(*[_type == "article" ].tag.value)
```

However When I run it in project I get data null. Here is how I try.

```
const query = groq`array::unique(*[_type == "article" ].tag.value)`
const { fetch } = useSanity()
const { data } = await useAsyncData("article tags", () => fetch(query))
```

I guess I'm doing something wrong with using [Sanity Groq Functions](https://sanity.nuxtjs.org/getting-started/usage).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was problem with different versions of Sanity API.

When using [@nuxtjs/sanity](https://sanity.nuxtjs.org/) module the API version by default is 1.

Inside my Sanity studio vision I was testing query with newer version therefor it worked.

I updated [sanity configuration](https://sanity.nuxtjs.org/getting-started/configuration#apiversion) inside my nuxt.config and now everything works.